# Get instagram post ids of public profile

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, instagram, instagram-api

I'm currently building a news page for a website and I want to embed Instagram posts together with kind of blog posts on a news page (so the Instagram posts are side-by-side and ordered together with the blog posts). Currently, I'm using this code to retrieve the posts of the user:

```
export const fetchInstagram = async () => {
    const result = [];
    let cursor;
    do {
        const params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams({
            fields: 'id,username,media_type,media_url,permalink,thumbnail_url,caption,timestamp',
            limit: "25",
            access_token: config.instagramAccessToken,
            ...(cursor && ({after: cursor}))
        })
        const response = await fetch("https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?" + params.toString(), {
            method: "GET"
        });
        const json = await response.json();
        cursor = json?.paging?.cursor?.after;
        result.push(...json.data);
    } while (cursor);

    return result;
}
```

However, this method has some problems:

1. As this code is called client-side (the page is static HTML), I would need to publish the access_token to all users
2. The access_token I generated using the facebook developer portal together with the Instagram Basic Display API is only valid for 60 days.

Do you have an idea how I can address these two issues? Is there a similar API where I can retrieve the timestamp and permalink of all posts from a user with public profile?

Comment: 1. Add a backend

Comment: Like Konrad said, you need a backend for this to work. The user makes a tailored request to your server, you figure everything out on the backend, and then present it to the user like magic! That way you don't give them the access_token.

Comment: Okay thanks! I'm currently using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/instagram-private-api) package to log in with username/password in the backend server too sollen the problem with the access tokens. Do you have a better alternative?